# How to make message bubble instead of using ready made in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create simple container for messages but failing for such easy code,

simply I want a container that having text of message, but failing to given width of container with length of text, it occupies entire maximum width and I don't want to give fixed width..

here is my coding

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Bubble Demo'),),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Column(children: [
          Align(
            alignment: index%4==0?Alignment.centerRight:Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
            height: 40,
            //width: 100,
            child: Center(
              //after applying this center, it occupies entire max width which i dont wont

              child: Text(
                  'Here is the Message Number '+index.toString(),),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: index%4==0?Colors.blue:Colors.orangeAccent,

            ),
        ),
          ),
          Divider(
            indent: 50,
          ),
        ],);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I need One More solution, It takes full length for long message how to apply some max width so that I does not stretch upto full width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Center widget will force the parent to take full widget if unbound.. You can add padding to the text and remove the center widget to make it aligned vertically in the center and remove the height of the Container too.. That way the text can stay dynamically sized if it recieves bigger text

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Bubble Demo'),),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context,index){
        return Column(children: [
          Align(
            alignment: index%4==0?Alignment.centerRight:Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
            padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 7),
            child: Text(
                'Here is the Message Number '+index.toString(),),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: index%4==0?Colors.blue:Colors.orangeAccent,

            ),
        ),
          ),
          Divider(
            indent: 50,
          ),
        ],);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the height constant you can use this solution.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Bubble Demo'),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: 20,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: _rightAlignment(index) ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: _rightAlignment(index) ? Colors.blue : Colors.orangeAccent,
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Here is the Message Number $index',
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                const Divider(
                  indent: 50,
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool _rightAlignment(int index) {
    return index % 4 == 0;
  }
}
```